# Flutter Animated Switcher with List of Widgets

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget

I have a `CustomScrollView` with several children. One children should always be displayed but the other ones should be displayed depending on a condition:

```
CustomScrollView(
                        controller: articleState.scrollController,
                        slivers: [
                          ArticleDetailPageHeader(widget.articleShort), // <- should always be displayed
                          ...condition
                              ? _buildShimmerWidgets() // returns List<Widget>
                              : _buildArticleWidgets(context, articleState), // ´´
                        ],
                      )
```

This is working. But I would like to use a `AnimatedSwitcher` so the UI looks a bit smoother.

I look into `AnimatedSwitcher` and it takes a `child` of the type `Widget`. Now that is the Problem! I have a `List<Widget`. Is there any workaround for this?

I hope my problem is clear, let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `Column` as the child for the `AnimatedSwitcher` and then pass the `List<Widget>` as children for the `Column`.

Comment: `A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderFlex` . I am using `Slivers` which makes it more difficult..

Comment: Oh ok, then try to use a SliverList or transfer the column into a sliver by putting it into a SliverToBoxAdapter.